# Implementing round buttons

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton, rounded-corners

I am building a simple app that displays a grid, similar to a guitar neck, and I wanted to draw oval buttons at each intersection of the grid, and attach behaviors to it, like tapping once for sound. Pretty straight forward stuff...

My question is about the use of class for the buttons.

I am able to draw some good looking buttons with `UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithOvalInRect:`
and now I want interactivity. I read in this forum from one developer that he used a button underneath an image to capture user interaction. I have tried that but I cannot fade out the button all together, as interaction is removed altogether.

1. Is it possible to draw rounded buttons with UIButton from interface builder?
2. What is best practice for something simple like drawing rounded buttons and capturing user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try layer.cornerRadius using the QuartzCore framework.

Or, just use an image as a custom button.

Comment: I'd go with the custom button, in my experience once you start using layer.cornerRadius you will lose some smoothness in any animations you perform - which in my opinion is a key aspect of any iOS app